# python rstrip usage within loop while reading csv file

Tags: python, django, csv, strip

I have a CSV file where I am looping and matching with my database for getting results according to these matches.

I encountered a problem in the case where there is a space at the end of the text. So I did my research and found that I need to add the `rstrip` function to remove spaces at the end of the text.

Here is my code:

```
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in data:
        line = row[0]
        cleanline = line.rstrip()
        lines.append(cleanline)
        query = line
```

The code is not working. I tried also strings like `/s` or `strip`, and replace functions as well but nothing is working. What can be the reason? What am I doing wrong?

CSV File with empty space at the end:

```
Sistem en az 23.8  inç boyutlarında olmalıdır. 
1 adet HDMI port olmalıdır.
```

Comment: Show sample of your data and format your code correctly.

Comment: Also, could you explain how this code doesn't fit your desired functionality, it very much depends on what you are trying to do. (or supply the error that is produced)

Comment: Your code looks fine for the purpose you described, but the last line is suspicious. `query` is using the original `line`; if that's where the space is causing problems, you need to have `query = cleanline`.

Comment: I tried to use cleanline too for the query (It needs to match with the database) but these approaches not working in the loop.Maybe I need to use rstip while reading the file. I don't know why.I will try Martin's code now.

Comment: You appear to have just a normal file, not a CSV file. There are no `|` delimiter characters on the lines?

Comment: yes true I am not using delimiter yet.Maybe in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

```
import csv

path = 'input.csv'
lines = []

with open(path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)

    for row in data:
        lines.append([c.strip() for c in row])

print(lines)
```

This removes all leading and trailing spaces from each cell in a row using the `strip()` command. Depending on your data, it might be just enough to add the additional `skipinitialspace=True` parameter. This though would not remove trailing spaces before the next delimiter. `newline=''` should also be used in Python 3.x when used with a `csv.reader()`.

---

The file you have given just contains lines of text, as such you could read it as follows:

```
lines = []

with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        lines.append(line.strip())

print(lines)
```

This would give you `lines` containing:

```
['Sistem en az 23.8  inç boyutlarında olmalıdır.', '1 adet HDMI port olmalıdır.']
```

Comment: end of my data within the csv file.There is only space after the point,which I want to remove:     CSV File:  desteklemelidir. CRLR     Your code adds in front of the text [' and at the end ']

Comment: Please add an example of your CSV file to your question, that way I would be able to recreate what you are getting. Also which version of Python are you using 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: I am using python 3 version. I put the csv file to the question

Comment: I need to manipulate the file before sending to the database for this I need to do while looping in for loop,right ? That's the only option ?